# Preserving Source IP in NGINX Ingress Controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

We're running an NGINX Ingress Controller as the 'front door' to our EKS cluster.

Our upstream apps need the client IP to be preserved, so I've had my ingress configmap configured to use the proxy protocol:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  custom-http-errors: 404,503,502,500
  ssl-redirect: "true"
  ssl-protocols: "TLSv1.2"
  ssl-ciphers: "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:!ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256"
  use-proxy-protocol: "true"
  proxy-real-ip-cidr: "0.0.0.0/0"
```

This sends the `X-Forwarded-For` header with the client IP to the upstream pods.  This seemed like it was working well, but once our apps started to receive heavier traffic, our monitors would occasionally report connection timeouts when connecting to the apps on the cluster.

I was able reproduce the issue in a test environment using JMeter.  Once I set `use-proxy-protocol` to `false`, the connection timeouts would no longer occur.  I started to look into the `use-proxy-protocol` setting.

The ingress docs describe the `use-proxy-protocol` setting [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#use-proxy-protocol)

However the docs also mention the settings "[enable-real-ip](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#enable-real-ip)" and "[forwarded-for-header](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#forwarded-for-header)"

At the link provided in the description for `enable-real-ip`, it says that I can set `forwarded-for-header` to value `proxy_protocol`.

Based on this, I've updated my Ingress configmap to:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx-test
data:
  custom-http-errors: 404,503,502,500
  ssl-redirect: "true"
  ssl-protocols: "TLSv1.2"
  ssl-ciphers: "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:!ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256"
  enable-real-ip: "true"
  forwarded-for-header: "proxy_protocol"
  proxy-real-ip-cidr: "0.0.0.0/0"
```

This configuration also properly sends the `X-Forwarded-For` header with the client IP to the upstream pods.  However, it also seems to eliminate the connection timeout issues I was seeing.  With this setup performance does not degrade anywhere near as badly as I ramp up the thread count in JMeter.

I would like to better understand the difference between these two configurations.  I’d also like to know what is the best practice most widely adopted method of achieving this among Kubernetes shops since this is likely a common use-case.

Comment: Hi, such opinion based question should be posted on different forums for example on serverfault.

Comment: Hello, thank you.  I'm trying to ask what is the objective and practical difference between these two configurations that accomplish the same result.  I'm also interested in the best practices around this.